Do Argo CD supports integration with DUO for SAML authentication
I'm interested in understanding whether Argo CD supports integration with DUO for SAML authentication. Specifically, does Argo CD work with DUO in a SAML setup?
If so, could you provide references or documentation on how to configure this integration?
I am trying this so far, not sure if this is correct, especially  redirectURI and entityIssuer
data:
  url: https://example.com
  dex.config: |
    logger:
      level: debug
      format: json
    connectors:
    - type: saml
      id: duo-saml
      name: Duo SAML
      config:
        ssoURL: https://my-login-url (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx/a/saml2)
        caData: |
           MY-BASE64-ENCODED-CERTIFICATE-DATA
        entityIssuer: https://example.com/api/dex/callback
        cert: <Base64-encoded-cert>                # Optional: Certificate to sign SAML requests
        key: <Base64-encoded-key>  
        redirectURI: https://example.com/api/dex/callback
        usernameAttr: email
        emailAttr: email
        groupsAttr: groups

